# Can't get text of an EditText on search button click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-view

I'm trying to search in a array with an edit text and a button, but I can't get the text from the EditText. If i change this `val textSearch : String = search.text.toString()` to `textSearch : String ="a"`, for example, all the code works, so the problem must be here. I tried all kinds of things but can't for some reason get the code to work.

```
class noticias : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticias, container, false) as View

        val listView : ListView = view?.findViewById(R.id.news_list_view)
        val btnSearch: Button = view?.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch)

        val search : EditText = view?.findViewById(R.id.searchText)
        val textSearch : String = search.text.toString()




        var names: ArrayList<NewsObject> = arrayListOf(
                NewsObject(R.drawable.bioron, "aaaa"),
                NewsObject(R.drawable.behind, "dddd"),
                NewsObject(R.drawable.bioron, "aaaa"),
                NewsObject(R.drawable.behind, "dddd"),
                NewsObject(R.drawable.bioron, "aaaa"),
                NewsObject(R.drawable.behind, "dddd"),
                NewsObject(R.drawable.juv, "jjjjkj")
        )

        listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(requireContext(),names)

        fun searchNews(search: String): ArrayList<NewsObject> {
            val namesTemp:ArrayList<NewsObject> =  arrayListOf()
            for(i in names.count()-1 downTo 0){
                Log.i("sda", names[i].title)
                if(names[i].title.contains(search.trim())){
                    namesTemp.add(names[i])
                }
            }

            return namesTemp


        }

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener() {


            if(textSearch.count() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),textSearch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(requireContext(),names)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(requireContext(), searchNews(textSearch))
            }
        }




        return view

    }

    data class NewsObject(val img: Int, val title: String)


    public class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, namesTemp: ArrayList<NewsObject>): BaseAdapter() {
        private val mContext: Context
        val names:ArrayList<NewsObject> =  namesTemp



        init {
            mContext = context
        }


        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return names.size
        }


        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }


        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return "TEST STRING"
        }


        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup?): View {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_row, viewGroup, false)

            val nameTextView = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_textView)
            nameTextView.text = names.get(position).title

            /*val positionTextView = rowMain.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.position_textview)
            positionTextView.text = names.get(position).img*/

            val img = rowMain.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img_new)
            img.setImageResource(names.get(position).img)


            return rowMain

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have this in `onCreateView`:

```kotlin
val textSearch : String = search.text.toString()
```

You're retrieving the text from the `EditText` as soon as the `EditText` is created, before the user has a chance to actually enter any text.  Thus, it's always the default value: an empty string, in this case.

You should move that line to your `OnClickListener` so that it retrieves the text only once the user clicks the button.

Comment: Or if the info is needed on Fragment startup, move it into `onViewCreated()`, Then the view will be created and populated by the time your code runs

Comment: @MatthewStrom Presumably the user needs a chance to enter text, which would mean that `onViewCreated` wouldn't work. I doubt the value they're trying to retrieve is going to be consistently available in the saved instance state (though what you describe would work if that were the case).